# if finally is always executed, why try returns unchaged value

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function f() {
    var a = 5;
    try {
        return a;
    } finally {
        a = 3;
    }
}

console.log(f()); // returns 5 instead of 3, why?
```

Comment: *"returns 5 instead of 3, why?"*. because there is no exception thrown, `5` is just returned without problem.

Comment: but finally is executed, no?

Comment: @dfsq: this means that finally is not always executed, only whenever an exception is thrown ?!

Comment: I've just put debugger inside finally, and it is being executed and variable `a` is changed to `3`

Comment: Interesting, actually `finally` is indeed executed. But looks like it can't change anything, since the value is already returned.

Comment: just add a console.log('finally') inside finally, it will print.

Comment: the problem here is variable scope/closure

Comment: `finally` is run after the `try`.

Comment: it may be that a is a variable local to f, and that finally executes as a different function with a different closure/scope

Comment: @Veverke Scope is not involved here, this has nothing to do with the scope of `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `a` is read when `return a;` is executed, then the finally block is executed. Changing the value of `a` after it's read won't change the return value.

If you write `return 3` in the finally block instead of `a = 3`, then you will see that the return value is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though finally block executes after `try`, it's can't change already returned value. Since `a` has primitive type, already returned value has no connection to the one left behind inside `f` function, because they are copies but not the same *instances* anymore.

To prove above, see how it would behave with objects that are passed by reference:

```js
function f() {
    var a = {value: 5};
    try {
        return a;
    } finally {
        a.value = 3;
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(f()));
```

Comment: thanks for the remark about changing the object instead of primitive inside `finally` block!

Comment: "Even though finally block executes after try, it's can't change already returned value." is untrue. You can `return` from within the `finally` and that will change the return value of the function.

Comment: @meagar Yes, it's correct. I meant that in this case changing `a` in finally block won't update already returned value. But yes, you can return *new* value.